# How do I specifiy the "-rdynamic" compiler/linker option in a zig.build file?

Tags: webassembly, zig

I'm using zig 0.10.1 and I'm trying to build a wasm library. Most tutorials show how to do this with `zig build-lib`. For a wasm library to export symbols one needs to specify the `-rdynamic` option. Now that I'm trying to build the library with a zig.build file, I can't pass `-rdynamic` as a compiler option anymore. Therefore the created library does not export my "exported functions" anymore.

First I tried `zig build -rdynamic` but it says it does not recognize this option and `zig build -h` doesn't seem to show any such option.

I also tried to look at the source of the builder passed to the build function in zig.build but the source for this std.build.Builder doesn't exist (no Builder.zig file): https://github.com/ziglang/zig/tree/0.10.x/lib/std/build
Am I looking in the wrong place?

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my simple build file:

```
const Builder = @import("std").build.Builder;
const logger = @import("std").log;
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *Builder) !void {
    // Standard target options allows the person running `zig build` to choose
    // what target to build for. Here we do not override the defaults, which
    // means any target is allowed, and the default is native. Other options
    // for restricting supported target set are available.
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});

    // Standard optimization options allow the person running `zig build` to select
    // between Debug, ReleaseSafe, ReleaseFast, and ReleaseSmall. Here we do not
    // set a preferred release mode, allowing the user to decide how to optimize.
    const optimize = b.standardOptimizeOption(.{});

    const lib = b.addSharedLibrary(.{
        .name = "math",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "math.zig" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = optimize,
    });
    b.installArtifact(lib);
}
```

This is math.zig:

```
extern "env" fn print(i32) void;

export fn add(a: i32, b: i32) void {
    print(a + b);
}
```

Loading the generated wasm file with [this](https://wasdk.github.io/wasmcodeexplorer/) WebAssembly Code Explorer indeed shows that `add()` was not exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lib.rdynamic = true;`

Really ought to be in `SharedLibraryOptions` but it's not at the moment.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Where did you get this information? Do you know where the source for std.build.Builder is?

Comment: It's in std.Build.CompileStep.